# How to pick particular object in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using ajax for cascading dropdown in my asp.net mvc project. I will drop code below
 #asset is the id of dropdown 1 
 #members is the id of dropdown 2

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {

  $("#asset").change(function() {
    debugger
    $.get("/Asset/Getmembers", {
      asset: $("#asset").val()
    }, function(data) {

      $("#members").empty();

      $.each(data, function(index, row) {

        $("#members").append($('<option></option>').attr('value', data[index].capacity).text(data[index].capacity));

      });
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If I select an asset the corresponding capacity will come. For example if asset 1 is selected the capacity for asset 1 say it is 7 will come in next drop down.
But I need to show from 1 to 7 in my capacity dropdown
If asset 2 is select,the capacity for asset 2 say it is 6 will come in next dropdown
But I need to show from 1 to 6 in my capacity dropdown

Answer (score 0):

It seems your API call is returning a number and not a list of numbers, so intead of using `each` try `for` loop.

```
for(var i=0;i<parseInt(data);i++)
{
 $("#members").append($('<option></option>').attr('value',i).text(i);
}
```

Comment: my data is like this if i check with debugger 0: {id: 3, asset: "Meeting room 1", capacity: 6, state: "Active"} length: 1

Comment: If I have correctly understood your requirement,as per your business logic, you need to select one asset , based on that asset that selected you need to fill the another dropdown with capacity.Please confirm if this requirement is clear, accordingly i'll modify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per data concern

```
let assetdata = JSON.Parse({id: 3, asset: "Meeting room 1", capacity: 6, state: "Active"});
```

reference to your above data

Step 1 : First your need keep your data constraints into separate variable

```
let assetid = assetdata.id;
let capacitylen = assetdata.capacity;
```

Step 2 : Then bind your cascading dropdown(Capcity) with require constraints:
 Note change your foreach loop

```
for(let i= assetid ;i<= parseInt(capacitylen);assetid++)
{
    $("#members").append($('<option></option>').attr('value',assetid ).text(assetid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the es6 spread operator?

```js
const data = [
{asset: "Meeting room 1", capacity: 6},
{asset: "Meeting room 2", capacity: 10},
{asset: "Meeting room 3", capacity: 12}
]

// handle click and add class
$( document ).ready(function() {
    for (var item of data) {
    $(`<option value="${item.capacity}">${item.asset}</option>`).appendTo($('#select1'));
  }
    
    $( "#select1" ).change(function() {
            $('#select2').empty().show();
          for (var item of [...Array(parseInt($(this).val())).keys()]) {
        $(`<option value="${item + 1}">${item + 1}</option>`).appendTo($('#select2'));
      }
  });  
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <select id="select1"></select>
 <select id="select2" style="display: none;">
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot hard code the data. i am getting it from database. How to use for loop till the capacity is 6 or 10

Comment: why would you want to hardcode the data? you would get it as you are already getting it. I don't understand your comment.  I had to hardcode it because obvisously I can't access your data.